# Cargar datos a un modelo con los datos del DataTable

Tags: c#

Tengo un modelo Empleado con 50 propiedades que representan las columnas de un DataTable.

Se puede cargar los datos del DataTable en el modelo sin tener que hacer esto:

```
empleado[0].Nombre = DataTable.Column[0].Row[0].Value;
empleado[0].Apellido= DataTable.Column[1].Row[0].Value;
empleado[0].Direccion= DataTable.Column[2].Row[0].Value;
...
...
...
empleado[0].Telefono = DataTable.Column[49].Row[0].Value;
```

?

El codigo es de orientación nada más, no es correcto el como leo los datos del DataTable creo, pero eso no importa.

Lo que quiero saber es si me puedo ahorrar el tener que acceder a cada propiedad del modelo "a mano".

Si las columnas del DataTable son del mismo Tipo que las propiedades de mi modelo, supongo que habrá alguna manera de cargar todo más facilmente.

Comment: Tu problema es como evitar escribir todos los gets de a uno para pasar los datos del table a la clase?

Comment: Sí, eso mismo. ¿Como podria hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví usando esta clase:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
    {
        try
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();

            foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
            {
                T obj = new T();

                foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                list.Add(obj);
            }

            return list;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Que se llama así:

```
var sColumn = "*";

                string query = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}", sColumn, fileName);

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                DataTable DTresult = new DataTable();
                DTresult.Load(reader);

                connection.Close();

                dataGridView1.DataSource = DTresult;

                List<Empleado> empleados = DTresult.DataTableToList<Empleado>();
```

Answer (score -2):

¡Hola Eduardo! Lo que podrías hacer son tres ciclos, uno que te recorra el usuario actual, otro que recorra las columnas y por ultimo otro que recorra las filas. Algo tal que así:

```
for(int i = 0; i < empleado.length; i++)
{
     for(int j = 0; j < TAMANO_COLUMNAS; j++)
     {
            for(int h = 0; h < TAMANO_FILAS; h++)
            {
                   empleado[i].Nombre = DataTable.Column[j].Row[h].Value;
                   empleado[i].Apellido= DataTable.Column[j].Row[h].Value;
                   empleado[i].Direccion= DataTable.Column[j].Row[h].Value;
                   ...
                   ...
                   ...
                   empleado[i].Telefono = DataTable.Column[j].Row[h].Value;
            }
     }
}
```

---

Así estarías cargando todo el numero de empleados respectivamente.

Comment: No entiendo esta respuesta. Mas alla que me parece que el problema de OP es justamente no hacer empleado[i].Nombre = DataTable.Column[j].Row[h].Value; empleado[i].Apellido= DataTable.Column[j].Row[h].Value;, si no decirle directamente a donde va cada columna, en tu codigo, vas a asignar a todas las variables del objeto, siempre el mismo valor. en tu ejemplo, nombre, apellido y direccion, tienen siempre el mismo valor, que en este caso siempre es el del telefono... raro...

Comment: Pero ahi nuevamente tendria que escribir todos los campos. No es lo que quiero y por eso mi pregunta.